# How to find out which dbus "services" are safe to remove?

Tags: configuration, d-bus

A look into `/usr/share/dbus-1/services` showed me an shockingly/impressively long list of "services".

1) What are those? Are they in general essential or bloat?
2) How to find out which are indeed needed?
3) How to disable/remove the ones that are bloat?

## Example for bloat?

there is a `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.gnome.Cheese.service`
which I seems to be related to the nice Webcam utility Cheese, which even though need I cannot imagine as a "service", and which I would rather start directly if needed.

the list here is this:

```
ca.desrt.dconf-editor.service
ca.desrt.dconf.service
org.a11y.Bus.service
org.bluez.obex.service
org.freedesktop.ColorHelper.service
org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Master.service
org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Providers.Example.service
org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Providers.Geonames.service
org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Providers.Gsmloc.service
org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Providers.Hostip.service
org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Providers.Localnet.service
org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Providers.Manual.service
org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Providers.Nominatim.service
org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Providers.Plazes.service
org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Providers.Skyhook.service
org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Providers.Yahoo.service
org.freedesktop.systemd1.service
org.freedesktop.Telepathy.AccountManager.service
org.freedesktop.Telepathy.Client.Logger.service
org.freedesktop.Telepathy.Logger.service
org.freedesktop.Telepathy.MissionControl5.service
org.gnome.baobab.service
org.gnome.Calculator.SearchProvider.service
org.gnome.Camera.service
org.gnome.Caribou.Antler.service
org.gnome.Caribou.Daemon.service
org.gnome.Cheese.service
org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider.service
org.gnome.ControlCenter.service
org.gnome.DiskUtility.service
org.gnome.evince.Daemon.service
org.gnome.FileRoller.ArchiveManager1.service
org.gnome.FileRoller.service
org.gnome.GConf.service
org.gnome.Identity.service
org.gnome.keyring.PrivatePrompter.service
org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter.service
org.gnome.OnlineAccounts.service
org.gnome.Shell.CalendarServer.service
org.gnome.Shell.HotplugSniffer.service
org.gnome.Shell.PortalHelper.service
org.gnome.Terminal.service
org.gnome.Totem.service
org.gtk.GLib.PACRunner.service
org.gtk.vfs.Daemon.service
org.gtk.vfs.Metadata.service
org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor.service
org.kde.kcookiejar5.service
org.kde.kglobalaccel.service
org.kde.kiod5.service
org.kde.kpasswdserver.service
org.kde.kscreen.service
org.kde.kssld5.service
org.kde.kwalletd5.service
org.kde.kwalletd.service
org.nemo.Preview.service
org.Nemo.service
org.xfce.Xfconf.service
```

Comment: 1) they're dbus service files, that's how stuff works [underneath](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/IntroductionToDBus/) 2) depends on your usage but most of them are needed 3) why would you want to remove them ? if you remove them a lot of stuff will no longer work on your system (including launchers which depend on those services); even if that wasn't the case, it's still pointless as they don't take up much space and they'd be back on the next system update anyway...

Comment: @don_crissti 3) I would like to remove them because it appeared to me to be rather (for me) not desirable stuff like geolocation, or at least not needed stuff like cheese (which after `mv /usr/share/dbus-1/org.gnome.Cheese{.service,.service.disabled}` still works perfectly). Indeed I have renamed most "service" files, which I hope will disable the "services" and had no ill effects yet. I will consult your "underneath" to get to know more

Comment: I really don't understand what you're after here... As I said, there is nothing to be gained from removing them (other than some KB of free space but not even that if you renamed them... there's plenty of "bloat" elsewhere if space is what you're after). But hey, your setup...

Answer (score 1):

Cheese will be started directly if needed *and not otherwise*

https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/DBusApplicationLaunching

unless you go around removing files belonging to installed packages, which in this specific case you can expect to break the ability to launch Cheese being from the GUI.

Comment: true, there is no `/usr/share/applications/cheese.desktop` file to allow GUI start, if not from a terminal `$> cheese &` one is really "needs" this dbus based startup service, if one is not running from the console. Anyways I deactiveted most services shown in the OP above without any ill effects yet (despite the not being able to graphically start cheese).

Comment: desktop file _does_ exist.  As per the link I posted, it is required to be named `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Cheese.desktop`.